# Autohotkey give a change only in specific language

Tags: autohotkey

```
#If !(langID = "EN")
:?:ign::ing
#If
```

I've tried to make an English filter with AutoHotKey but which is not apply on other languages.

I tested to indicate `LangID = 0x0409` / `langID = 0000409` but no works, how to make this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#If !(GetKeyboardLanguage(WinActive("A")) = 0x0409)  ; English  ; "!" means "NOT"

    :?:ign::ing

#If

GetKeyboardLanguage(_hWnd=0){
    if !_hWnd
        ThreadId=0
    else
        if !ThreadId := DllCall("user32.dll\GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Ptr", _hWnd, "UInt", 0, "UInt")
            return false    
    if !KBLayout := DllCall("user32.dll\GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", ThreadId, "UInt")
        return false    
    return KBLayout & 0xFFFF
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/116538-detect-which-language-is-currently-on/#entry672236

Comment: Thought the end of `#if` make return but it was complex then I thought. thank you!